# asp.net C#: PUT httpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an asp.net page that receives a PUT request with the following form:

PUT -Filename- 
Header1: value1 
Header2: value1

i've managed to extract the headers..and MethodType (PUT), however i cant figure out a way to extract the -filename- , i cant even find a variable that sees it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid HTTP request. What follows the `PUT` verb should be the name of the resource your are putting to which in your case is the asp.net page. So a valid request should be:

```
PUT /yourpage.aspx
Headre1: value1
Header2: value2
```

In this case of course you already know `yourpage.aspx` as you are inside this page.